# Languages: Prove or Disprove that $A^* = B^* \rightarrow A=B$

Tags: formal-languages, kleene-star

A colleague and I with pretty low-grade practical backgrounds decided it's time to try learning theory. This question is asked in a slide-deck he tracked down somewhere or another online without an answer to go with it. We're both leaning towards a simple disproof by Counter-Example:
$A = \{a,b\}$
$B = \{ab,a,b\}$
But we aren't sure if alphabets are "allowed" to contain redundancies like the one in B. Any quick guidance from the community?

Comment: Are they alphabets or languages?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are indeed meant to be alphabets here, they would contain only symbols, and your counterexample isn't valid. In fact, if $A$ and $B$ are alphabets, the claim is true.

However, I would rather expect $A$ and $B$ to be formal languages here, in which case you have found a perfectly reasonable counterexample.